# Unity3D WebGL template has white stripes on the sides in landscape orientation

Tags: html, css, ios, unity-game-engine, webgl

Hello everyone Please help me, I have a WebGL template for the game and it perfectly stretches the game space to the entire size of the browser on desktop and android browsers, however, on iOS devices with horizontal orientation, white stripes appear on the sides that cannot be removed in any way, what can be done in this situation?[image]

I used a css template

```
* {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    padding: constant(safe-area-inset-top) constant(safe-area-inset-right) constant(safe-area-inset-bottom) constant(safe-area-inset-left);
    padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
}


#unity-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#unity-container.unity-desktop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#unity-container.unity-mobile {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#unity-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    
    { background:{ #ffffff;} }
}

.unity-desktop #unity-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

.unity-mobile #unity-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#unity-canvas+* {
    z-index: 2;
}
```